# Facing issues on ultragrid filtering

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

We are constantly loading data in ultragrid & updating the bindinglist continuously. All the updates are showing up on the grid but when we try to filter the data, filter UI is closing up. Unless all data gets loaded on the grid, we are not able to filter the data.

```
ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.FilterUIType = FilterUIType.FilterRow;
```

Any pointers why filtering UI is closing up & not staying open to let us select any value to filter on ?

Which events force filter UI to close?

Thanks

Comment: Well if you rebind the grid while the filter dropdown is open this will close it since it needs to be repopulated with the new values. There is no way around that. Maybe one possible solution would be to temporarily stop updating the data while the filter is dropped down.